# Allocated Dynamically Array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, memory, malloc

i'm really stuck.
I pust a big part of code you can try to run it on in online c compiler. My problem is weird, every time after 2 iteration i lost the data on spliter[0][0] when i mean "lost" is modified, for better understand please look what is printing it.
Inside

Inside the loop that iterates I wanted to see if the characters were well allocated in the present time and this is the case, only afterwards when I want to check it is impossible for me to do anything.

My program boils down to separating one character string according to another and dynamically allocating these character strings in my split. Each separator character counts as separator.

I have already prepared the test in comment. I really need help, too long time im stuck here..

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_c(char c, char *cha) {
    while (*cha) {
        if (*cha == c) {
            return (1);
        }
        cha++;
    }
    return (0);
}

int ct_str(char *str, char *cha) {
    int sw;
    int nbr;
    char item;

    nbr = 0;
    while (*str) {
        if (!(is_c(*str, cha)) && *str >= 33 && *str <= 127 && sw == 1) {
            sw = 0;
            nbr+=1;
        }
        str++;
        while (is_c(*str, cha)) {
            str++;
            sw = 1;
        }
    }
    return (nbr);
}

int no_blk(char *str, int position, char *cha) {
    while (!is_c(str[position], cha)) {
        if (str[position] >= 33 && str[position] <= 127)
            return (1);
        position++;
    }
    return (0);
}

int get_size(char *str, int position, char *cha) {
    int item;
    item = position;
    int j;
    j = 0;

    while (str[item]) {
        if (is_c(str[item], cha))
            return (j);
        item++;
        j++;
    }
    return (0);
}

void split_this(char **split, char *str, char *cha) {
    int i;
    int level;
    int sw;
    int e;
    level = 0;
    i = 0;

    int item = 0;
    int element = 0;

    while(str[i + 1]) {
        e = 0;
        while(is_c(str[i], cha)) {
            sw = 1;
            i++;
        }
        if(sw == 1 && (!is_c(str[i], cha)) && no_blk(str, i, cha)) {
            split[level] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * get_size(str, i, cha) + 1);
            e = i;

            //printf("%i \n", get_size(str, i, cha));

            while(e - i < get_size(str, i, cha)) {
                split[level][e - i] = str[e];
                //printf("%c", split[level][e - i]);
                split[level][(e + 1) - i] = '\0';
                e++;
            }
            printf("%c", split[0][0]);
            sw = 0;
            level++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    free(split);

    /*
    int it = 0;
    int ee;

    while(split[it]) {
        ee = 0;
        while(split[it][ee]) {
            printf("%c", split[it][ee]);
            ee++;
        }
        it++;
    }
    */
}

void ft_split(char *str, char *cha) {
    char **spliter = NULL;
    spliter = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * ct_str(str, cha) + 1);
    split_this(spliter, str, cha);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //if (argc == 3)
        //ft_split(argv[1], argv[2]);
    ft_split("%%am%s%s%ss%%s%%%qsdqsd%%%on%vs%lre%" , "%%");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings on this line? `ft_split("%%am%s%s%ss%%s%%%qsdqsd%%%on%vs%lre%" "%%");`

Comment: In `spliter = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * ct_str(str, cha) + 1);` did you mean `sizeof(char*)` where you have `sizeof(char)`? And to parenthesize? So `spliter = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (ct_str(str, cha) + 1));`

Comment: @user3386109 yes its the goal every caracter of the separator is a separator

Comment: sizeof(char) and sizeof(char*) are different ??

Comment: Yep, try `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(char*));`

Comment: Oh damn yes of course.. guys i lost some many hours for this stupid forogot. MEA CULPA and thanks y'all ! Stackeroverflow is very efffective.

Comment: The general rule when using `malloc()` is that the type in `sizeof` should have 1 less `*` than the type you're assigning to.

Comment: @Barmar True but the better rule: `sizeof *p`

Comment: @Barmar what means size of *p

Comment: @pharaoh111 Instead of using `sizeof (TYPE)` use `sizeof *VARIABLE` where `VARIABLE` is the variable you're assigning the result to.  That way it will always be the correct type.

Comment: Oh okay, its detect automatically i see. thx @Barmar